# Objective C UI Collection issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading, objective-c-blocks

Description :-

Hello , When we are running this code when is cell relocate image is changing on scrolling.

Please let me know how to fix.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell )collectionView:(UICollectionView )collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cellidentifier";
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString * string = [_temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // retrive image on global queue
        UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:     [NSURL URLWithString:string]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.imageView.image = img;
        });
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it would be better to load the data into your _model_ not into the _view_, and when the _model_ is ready you could populate the _view_ from your _model_ – as usually it would be the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that if the cells get reused the previous image might still be loading or be set. You can override the cell's `prepareForReuse` to `nil` the image. For asynchronous loading of images you should check if the cell's model object is stil the same as when you started the loading, if not, then don't set the image as it arrived too late.

Comment: Hello , We tried the same idea which is mentioned here but using your idea it is not showing any images like old one or new one. Any other solution.?